# How to pass value from one frame while calling an asp classic file with parameter

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have two iframes. I want to pass the value from one frame while calling an asp file from server so that the output of that asp file is displayed on second frame. However, one parameter 'subfl' is not taking the reference value, but it is taking only what i have typed. How to pass the value as reference with the parameter 'subfl' while calling a asp file (meetdatshow.asp).

```
<font size=3 color="#000000"><input type="radio" name="ifr" value="meetdatshow.asp?subfl=parent.frames['iframe_a'].document.forms.form1.comnm.value" onClick="self.frames['iframe_b'].location.href=this.value; return true;">Refresh</font>
```

Comment: Why use frames? Yuck!

Comment: use of frame is not the difficulty. It is working perfectly. But I want that 'subfl' parameter should pass its value by reference not the one that is typed.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to include JavaScript in the value of your input, which is just possible. Instead, you should move it to the `onclick` event:

```
<input type="radio" name="ifr" value="meetdatshow.asp" onclick="self.frames['iframe_b'].location.href=this.value+'?subfl='+parent.frames['iframe_a'].document.forms.form1.comnm.value;return true;">
```